# java date daylight saving

Tags: java, date

I just printed new Date() in my box, and it always returns the older time which corresponds to EST, however the date command in the box returns the exact time after moving to EDT, IS there anything that need to be done for the new Date() to return the exact date ? I do not want any alternate java commands, but want the Date to work as it is expected, Am I missing something ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: What do you mean "the older time" and "the exact time"?  EDT is currently in effect, so if that's what it's returning then I'd say it's working correctly.

Comment: Matt Johnson, I have changed to EDT and EST respectively 

There is nothing more in the code than

System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: @user3487741 (a) No need to pass `System.currentTimeMillis()` to the constructor of java.util.Date. The no-arg constructor does that automatically. (b) Are you understanding that a j.u.Date has no time zone, yet its `toString` implementation applies the JVM's default time zone (annoying and confusing behavior)? (c) Bad habit to use the 3 or 4 letter time zone codes. They are neither standardized nor unique. Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). (d) You asked for no alternates, but really, j.u.Date is awful. Use Joda-Time or java.time.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

`Calendar.getInstance()` gives you a Calendar object initialized with the current date / time, using the default `Locale` and `TimeZone`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the below code would be useful for your case.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss z"); //Date format
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT"));   //set Timezone
df.format(new Date());
```

Thanks.